# INNER JOIN: Unir las filas de una tabla solo cuando tienen un ID en común (SQlite)

Tags: sqlite

Quiero hacer una tabla a partir de otra.
Lo único que hago es sumar dos filas si la columna "position" de la primera tabla que tenen el mismo valor.
Pero además me gustaría que solo se sumaran entre si las que tengan el mismo valor en la columna "pass_id".
He conseguido hacer la primera condición pero la segunda no me funciona bien.

Esta es la sentencia que estoy usando:

```
      "INSERT INTO TRADES(PASS_ID,TIME_IN,TICKET,TYPE,VOLUME,SYMBOL,PRICE_IN,TIME_OUT,PRICE_OUT,COMMISSION,SWAP,PROFIT) "
      "SELECT "
      "   d1.pass_id as pass_id,"
      "   d1.time as time_in,"
      "   d1.position_id as ticket,"
      "   d1.type as type,"
      "   d1.volume as volume,"
      "   d1.symbol as symbol,"
      "   d1.price as price_in,"
      "   d2.time as time_out,"
      "   d2.price as price_out,"
      "   d1.commission+d2.commission as commission,"
      "   d2.swap as swap,"
      "   d2.profit as profit "
      "FROM DEALS d1 "
      "INNER JOIN DEALS d2 ON d1.position_id=d2.position_id AND d1.pass_id=d2.pass_id "
      "WHERE d1.entry=0 AND d2.entry=1  ;
```

Y esta es la parte que me está fallando

```
AND d1.pass_id=d2.pass_id
```

Y esta una captura de algunos datos de la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como se hace correctamnte?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ese insert y select seguidos tienen mala pinta... parece que te esta operando el segundo where con el insert, en lugar de con el select... Has probado a hacer un select directamente con ese join y ver que resultados te da? para comprobarlo, añade el campo d2.pass_id para ver que los dos ids sean correctos en el resultado de la select

Comment: Ok, intentaré hacer lo que dices. Muchas gracias!!